# Make swipe and scroll work together

Tags: android

I have a view  to which I attached a GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener listener in order to implement swipe to left/right. In this view I also have a textview for which I set ScrollingMovementMethod() and also specified vertical scrollbars for it in xml. Swipe worked fine before implementing scrolling, but with scroll swipe detection isn't working anymore.

Why ScrollingMovementMethod() blocks the detection of swipe and how can it be managed in order to have both swipe and scroll?

Swipe implementation:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeGestureDetector());

gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
};

container.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    flipCard();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    flipCard();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Scroll:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerText);
answerText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: see my ZoomView and its implementation of GestureListener, code here https://github.com/pskink/ZoomView